# NFC p2p tag interception

Tags: android, eclipse, nfc, nfc-p2p

I am building an Android app using Eclipse and Android SDK. 
I would like to implement an NFC p2p function in my app in the sense that when you place the 2 phones back to back, both send a string and receive a string automatically. This would of course happen in a separate activity. I have managed to send a custom tag (String) but have been unable to intercept it and use it afterwards in the app code. How can i do this?

This is what i have so far.

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
public NfcAdapter mAdapter;
PendingIntent mPendingIntent;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


     mAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);

     NdefRecord rec = NdefRecord.createUri("www.stackoverflow.com"); 
     NdefMessage ndef = new NdefMessage(rec);

     mAdapter.setNdefPushMessage(ndef, this);
 }
```

I have spent a lot of time trying to find and understand solutions to intercept the tag. Unsuccessfully.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Post some code and explain what you have already tried.

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of [NFC P2P tag intercept](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30186739/2425802) asked by the same user.