# NFC P2P tag intercept

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc, ndef, nfc-p2p

I am building an Android app using Eclipse and Android SDK. I would like to implement an NFC P2P function in my app in the sense that when you place the 2 phones back to back, both send a string and receive a string automatically. This would of course happen in a separate activity. I have managed to send a custom tag (String) but have been unable to intercept it and use it afterwards in the app code. How can I do this?

This is what I have so far:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public NfcAdapter mAdapter;
PendingIntent mPendingIntent;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


     mAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);

     NdefRecord rec = NdefRecord.createUri("www.stackoverflow.com"); 
     NdefMessage ndef = new NdefMessage(rec);

     mAdapter.setNdefPushMessage(ndef, this);
 }
```

I have spent a lot of time trying to find and understand solutions to intercept the tag. Unsuccessfully.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the foreground dispatch system to receive the NDEF message within your activity:

1. In `onResume()`:

   ```
   PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
   NfcAdapter nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
   nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, null, null);
   ```
2. Do something upon receiving the intent:

   ```
   public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
       ...
   }
   ```